# Rotating 3D plots

Tags: plotting

```
    p1 = Plot3D[Sin[x] t, {x, 0, 2}, {t, 0, 2}, Mesh -> None, Mesh -> All,
   MeshFunctions -> Automatic, PlotTheme -> "Business", 
  PlotStyle -> Purple, PlotPoints -> 50, 
  AxesLabel -> {x, t, Rotate["f(x,t)", 90 Degree] }, 
  PlotRange -> All ] 
p2 = Plot3D[Cos[x] t, {x, 0, 2}, {t, 0, 2}, Mesh -> None, Mesh -> All,
   MeshFunctions -> Automatic, PlotTheme -> "Business", 
  PlotStyle -> Blue, PlotPoints -> 50, 
  AxesLabel -> {x, t, Rotate["f(x,t)", 90 Degree] }, 
  PlotRange -> All ] 
p3 = Show[p1, p2 ]
```

[image]

I want to rotate 3d graphics above by code as follows :

[image]

But when I rotate the graphic by mouse, axes labels, etc. can't be rotated. Please find the green markers in the second graphic above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you included both `Mesh -> None` and `Mesh -> All` it is not clear what you want. To relocate the axes labels use the option [`AxesEdge`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AxesEdge.html)

```
Plot3D[{Sin[x] t, Cos[x] t}, {x, 0, 2}, {t, 0, 2},
 MeshStyle -> Gray,
 PlotStyle -> {Purple, Blue},
 PlotPoints -> 50,
 AxesLabel -> {x, t, "f(x,t)"},
 PlotRange -> All,
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions",
 SphericalRegion -> True,
 ViewPoint -> {1.3, 2.4, 2.},
 AxesEdge -> {{1, -1}, {1, -1}, {1, -1}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. That's what I want. Can you explain more how to decide right numbers 1.3, 2.4, 2  in  `ViewPoint -> {1.3, 2.4, 2.}` ?

Comment: When entering the option `ViewPoint`, one of the choices in the context-sensitive menu was `{1.3, -2.4, 2.}`, I choose that and then reversed the `y` coordinate to approximate what you had shown. Alternatively, you could use a `Manipulate` with three controls for the `ViewPoint` coordinates and play with it until you find what you want.